# How to commit only modified (and not new or deleted) files?

Tags: git, version-control

`git status` shows a bunch of files which were modified and some which were deleted. I want to first commit the modified files and then the deleted ones. I don't see any option in `git add` that enables me to do this. How can I do it?

**EDIT**: As pointed out, `git add` wouldn't have staged the deleted files anyway, so `git add .` would do. But it has the side-effect of including files which weren't tracked, which I would also like to avoid. I have changed the title of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The following command should do the trick:

```
git commit -a
```

or

```
git commit -am "commit message"
```

From the [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book:

> Providing the -a option to the git commit command makes Git automatically stage every file that is already tracked before doing the commit

Comment: is there any downside to using mutliple flags so as to add message as well? eg git commit -am "updated files"

Comment: @sayth, in this case, there is no downside. It is a matter of preference - one may want to use a text editor for writing commit messages.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The -a will include both: modified and deleted files. This is completely wrong and should be deleted.

Comment: @WowPress.host, while it may not be exactly what the questioner asked, it sure worked for my purposes of committing everything touched by a bash script.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith exactly, it's useful answer, but to another question :). Not to what was asked for. One posted by "Pedro d'Aquino" is the correct here...

Comment: Why would you not want to commit deleted files ?? This is exactly what I need and I feel needs to be done by default during a commit. Why would I not want to commit modified files ??

Comment: The answer is not correct. It will include all modified/added/deleted files.

Answer (score 36):

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M | xargs git add`

(based on [Charles Bailey's answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121452/with-git-how-do-i-commit-a-load-of-deleted-files-in-one-go/2121476#2121476)))

Comment: Its a bit cumbersome to do so much just to push modified files. Don't you think?

Comment: @Cherian one could make an alias of this

Answer (score 28):

You could use:

```
git add -u
```

to stage already tracked files that have been modified since last commit.

From [git-add](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) man page:

> -u
>   --update
>
> Only match  against already tracked files in the index rather than the working tree. That means that it will never stage new files, but that it will stage modified new contents of tracked files and that it will remove files from the index if the corresponding files in the working tree have been removed.
>   If no  is given, default to "."; in other words, update all tracked files in the current directory and its subdirectories.

Not sure when this feature has been added though.

Comment: `git add` will `commit` files?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke No, but it will add files to the staging area, making them ready to be commited to a new commit in your currently checked-out branch. You'll need to commit the staged changes with `git commit` afterwards.

Comment: `git add -u ; git commit` is essentially equivalent to `git commit -a`. It will commit file deletion, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy You're absolutely right ! My mistake !

Comment: Add only modified `.cpp` files: `git add -u *.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing something but git add doesn't include deleted files, you have to use git rm to remove those:

```
mkdir git-test
cd git-test
git init
touch a
touch b
touch c
git add .
git commit -m "Initial"
echo "a" > a
echo "b" > b
rm c
git status

# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   a
#       modified:   b
#       deleted:    c
#

git add .

# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   a
#       modified:   b
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    c
#

git commit -m "Changed"
git status

# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    c
#

git rm c
git commit -m "Deleted"
```

And git log shows three commits.

Comment: You are right that `git add` wouldn't have staged the deleted files (being very new to git, I didn't know that yet -- thanks). But `git add .` seems to add untracked files, which is something I would like to avoid, so the `xargs` answer still has some usefulness.

Comment: Do you still at some point want to add those untracked files? If not, then you could add them to the .gitignore file.

Comment: I didn't know about .gitignore, thanks. My current need is simply to organize the commits so they actually reflect one atomic operation (e.g. "fixed bug" is separated from "added feature"), so these files will be commited at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful with using git commit -a -- unless you have made sure that your .gitignore file has ALL files that you do NOT want added there

I have used git commit -a many times in areas where this was not the case, and I ended up having to clean up / delete temporary files etc. from git repository

Comment: No, it's not `git commit -a` who did this. `git commit -a` does *not* add new files, it just commits all changes to already tracked files. Probably you ran `git add .` to end up in this situation.

Comment: Right it does **not** add new files but it deletes files that have been deleted. "-a, -all Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not affected."

Answer (score 0):

git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for enter here commit:
(use "git add ..`enter here`." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore …" to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   src/components/Header.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

If we try to add  particular modified file only then using git add "Modified file" will throw an error
$ git add Header.js
fatal: path spec 'Header.js' did not match any files

So I used this and pushed
Git add -u // To update the modified file.

git commit -m "Header.js".

git push

This worked fine for me.