# How to get changes from master branch to local branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have, what I assume, is a typical workflow.

Our project works with pull requests.

To develop new feature I create a dev. branch.
By the time I am finished with the feature some changes were made in master
so I want to get those changes into my branch so I make pull request.

From what I've read on the internet there are two options for that:

1. merge
2. rebase

However, I tried both of them but when I make pull request it shows that all files were changed in this pr.

Here is what I did:

on the branch

```
-- git commit -a -m "changes i made on my branch" 
-- git checkout master
-- git fetch upstream
-- git merge upstream/master
-- git checkout mybranch
-- git merge master (or rebase)
-- git push origin mybranch
```

result -- merge commit in the history shows files changes: 90

What is the correct way to get updates from master into my branch?

Similar situation happens when somebody reviews my pr and I need to update my pr. Once again, I end up needing the changes from master.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: @Joe it's not when to use this or that. in both cases i get the same result

Comment: If you get tons of files changed when in fact you only edited a few files, check the diffs. If it automatically changed tabs to spaces then you might want to look into your line ending settings.

Comment: @miva2 nope, it actually shows some changes that were made by other people as mine

Comment: This is problem for me too.  I'm beginner in Git and still grokking all git commands.  Sadly, I haven't found a simple solution just to push "my" changes only and not 100 other files committed by others in master.

Answer (score 33):

You can pull changes from master to your branch with:

```
git checkout my_branch    # move on your branch (make sure it exists)
git fetch origin          # fetch all changes
git pull origin master    # pull changes from the origin remote, master branch and merge them into my_branch
git push origin my_branch # push my_branch
```

**Please note**, based on new changes to branch default name on some git repository providers you can have a **master** branch named **main**

Comment: did you mean "git pull origin master"? i cannot pull origin my_branch becase my branch is not yet pushed

Comment: @rigby yes, sorry for mistake.

Comment: when you are finally pushing it should be : git push origin my_branch

Answer (score 3):

> -- git checkout mybranch
>
> -- git merge master (or rebase)

Till this it is correct

After this you are directly pushing to your branch, before this just add and commit like this.

> -- git add .
>
> -- git commit -m "msg after merging"
>
> -- git push origin mybranch

This will merge Master Branch Code with your branch (i.e. mybranch) & will push the code to origin

Comment: i commit all my changes for my feature before switching to master to check for changes there.
but i tried what you suggested and still get the same problem: Showing  90 changed files

what i did:

...
-- git checkout mybranch

-- git merge master (no conflicts)
-- git add .
-- git commit -m "msg after merging" (git says nothing to commit)
-- git push origin mybranch
result: 90 changed files

Comment: what is the final result you want ?@rigby

Comment: i want git to show that only files that i actually changed as "changed".
for now it shows that ALL (90) files were changed.

Comment: This post might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873976/how-to-commit-only-modified-and-not-new-or-deleted-files