# Is there a way to stage only modified files using "git add" ? (ie. ignore additions and deletions)

Tags: git, command-line

`git add -u` - *adds only deleted or modified files*.
`git add --ignore-removal` - *adds only add and modified* files
but,
is there a way to combine these both to add only modified files and ignore the additions and deletions

Comment: ignore addition or deletion of files in the projects  or of the code in the files of project, please describe briefly your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to commit only modified (and not new or deleted) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873976/how-to-commit-only-modified-and-not-new-or-deleted-files)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2121476/9574767) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874015/9574767). Apparently there is no direct way in Git to do this, but a simple workaround is:

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M | xargs git add`

Comment: If the paths have whitespaces: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs git add` .